# Create an azure eventhub consumer group via net core SDK?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-eventhub

The older `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` library has a call `CreateConsumerGroupIfNotExists` to create a consumer group on an azure eventhub. However, this is Net Framework 4.6 only.  I'm trying to figure out how to create a consumer in `netstandard2.0` from C# but I don't see an equivalent.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: ... I think there should be a call in [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiveBus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus?view=azure-dotnet) but I don't see one.

Comment: ... or [`Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.servicebus?view=azure-dotnet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can directly use the REST API [`Create consumer group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/create-consumer-group) to create EventHubs Consumer Group in any programming language.

In your scenario using C#, there is an API of Azure SDK for .NET [`ConsumerGroupsOperationsExtensions.CreateOrUpdate(IConsumerGroupsOperations, String, String, String, String, ConsumerGroup) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.eventhub.consumergroupsoperationsextensions.createorupdate?view=azure-dotnet) that you can use. And according to the information from NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2017, as the figure below, the related package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub` supports `Netstandard.Library (>=1.6.1)`, so it should also support your current environment `netstandard2.0`.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what is implementing IConsumerGroupsOperations?  I don't see what object that's supposed to be extending....  And why would it require a ConsumerGroup and get a ConsumerGroup back?

Comment: Ok, I managed to figure out that this is extending an `EventHubManagementClient`, and I was able to call `CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync` to create a new consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Pan is correct in pointing out the C# API call for this.  Here are some more details:

- Create a *service principal* in Azure (or use an existing one)
- Grant this service principal "Owner" access to the Event Hubs Instance (under IAM => "Role Assignments" in the portal)

The variables in the code below come from the service client, the event hub and the subscription:

```
private static async Task EnsureConsumerGroup(string consumerGroupName)
{
    var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{MY_TENANT_ID}");

    var token = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
        "https://management.core.windows.net/",
        new ClientCredential(MY_CLIENT_ID, MY_CLIENT_SECRET)
    );
    var serviceClientCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token.AccessToken);
    var eventHubManagementClient = new EventHubManagementClient(serviceClientCredentials)
    {
        SubscriptionId = MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    };

    var consumerGroupResponse = await 
eventHubManagementClient.ConsumerGroups.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(
        MY_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        MY_NAMESPACE_NAME,
        MY_EVENT_HUB_NAME,
        consumerGroupName,
        new ConsumerGroup() // I don't know what this parameter is supposed to do.
    );
}
```

Presumably you would handle the error condition in `consumerGroupResponse.Response` as well.

See also:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-hubs-dotnet-management